# Is this the correct reason that the sequence cannot converge to zero?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, riemann-integration, monotone-functions

Let the sequence $\left\{a_n\right\}$ is defined as:
$$a_n=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}$$

Basically the terms of the sequence are $\frac{1}{2},\frac{7}{12},\frac{37}{60},...$

Now we need to find $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n$. It is pretty obvious that its a Riemann summation and we get the answer as $\ln 2$.

But if a novice solves this, he/she will take individual limits as follows:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n+1}+\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n+2}+....+\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{2n}=0+0+0...+0=0$$

But if we observe that:
$$a_{n+1}-a_{n}=\frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n+2}-\frac{1}{n+1}-\cdots-\frac{1}{2n}=\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}>0$$
So the sequence $\left\{a_n\right\}$ is increasing and bounded below by $\frac{1}{2}$.So incase it converges it converges to a value more than $\frac{1}{2}$.Hence the limit $0$ is the wrong answer.Is this reasoning valid or can we reason in a better for a novice calculus student?

Comment: Yes, I think this is a good explanation to a novice student : to convince them of the fact that this sequence doesn't converge to zero. Having said that , this is *one* example : so for a novice, the key takeaway should be the fact that you can't interchange the limit and a sum just like that, if the number of terms in the sum depends upon the variable moving to the limit. It needs more considerations, and cannot be handwaved across in favour of merely showing that the reasoning for this one problem is wrong.

Comment: I don't believe there is a such a thing as 'the correct reason' why a mathematical proposition is true. There are several proofs involving statements that are known to be true, there are chains of derivations, starting from a set of axioms, but no correct reason.

Comment: I think if a student came to me with that reasoning, I would ask: How many zeros are there, exactly, on that $0+0+0\ldots+0$ line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, the simplest approach consists in observing that each term in the sum is $\ge\frac 1{2n}$, and that there are $n$ terms. Therefore
$$a_n=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+3}+\dots+\frac{1}{n+n}\ge n\cdot\frac1{2n}=\frac12.$$

Comment: Thanks Bernard that was an awesome trick

Comment: The brave anonymous downvoter struck again!

Answer (score 5):

Well, the thing to note is that in the limit, "you are summing up infinitely many $0$s".

---

To convince a novice that the argument is not correct, you can give an even simpler example. Consider $$a_n = \underbrace{\frac{1}{n} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n}}_{n \text{ times}}.$$
By the same argument, you would get $a_n \to 0$ but in fact, we have $a_n = 1$ for all $n \ge 1$.

---

<strike>To convince them that the limit in your particular case is not $0$, I think what you have written is a simple enough reason.</strike>

**Edit:** See [Bernard's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4180902/427810).

Comment: Upvote to your example also. nice